# Aws pipeline for deploying docker compose app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, devops, amazon-ecs

I have docker-compose with four containers:

1. Web App
2. Prometheus Client
3. Promtail
4. Opentelemetry

All these four containers have an aws ecr link and docker-compose.yml comtains the necessary commands to run these four containers and link them to work together.

I can deploy it using the ecs-cli from my workstation by running ecs service up command in the directory containing the compose file.

I want to automate this deployment so that the web app code is taken from the github repo and whenever there is a change the image and everything gets redeployed. Can someone please guide me how can I achieve this?

My pipeline idea:
Github->ecr image-> redeploy docker-compose

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. There are multiple ways to achieve this. It sounds like you want to use GitHub actions, and that is a perfectly valid method of achieving this. So, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @MarkB I can’t find an appropriate way. I don’t want want to use github actions i want to stick to aws. Anyways i have made a deployment using code pipeline idk if it’s the most appropriate way. Also i want to scale this as well. Any tips or blogs?